# IOS Face Detection - Detect Eye width

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am using CIFaceFeature to detect eye co-ordinates. And from eye co-ordinates i am adding eyebrow image to face. But this will be static for me. it will not fit for all human faces. Is there any method to get eye width? `

```
for (CIFaceFeature *faceFeature in features) {
            // Draw a highlight around the subject's face.

            CGRect faceRect = faceFeature.bounds;
CGPoint leftPoint = [self leftEyePositionForImage:self.imageView.image inView:self.imageView.bounds.size];
            CGPoint rightPoint = [self rightEyePositionForImage:self.imageView.image inView:self.imageView.bounds.size];
}
```

My code is like above. After getting center point of eyes i am adding UIImageview above that center point.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my app. The way to do it is use a reference face of a known size and get the distance between the eyes using Pythagoras theorem (a2 + b2 = c2).

Once you know distance of N requires an image of a certain size you can establish that if the distance is 1.5 times then the eyebrow image needs increasing in size by that amount too.

You can also get the angle of the face by using atan2 on the eye points to get the rotation for the eyebrows too.